# How often do you need TURN server for webRTC app

Tags: tcp, webrtc, p2p

I am new to webRTC, and i know that for it to work, i need to have a STUN server to exchange ip addresses, but sometimes that isn't enough because the users have firewalls, so i need to relay my data through a TURN server, the question is, if i were to build an app, how often am i gonna need a TURN server, in other words, how many people (approximately) usually use firewalls, you can give an approximate percentage if you have experience with webRTC.

if am not clear, i want an answer that's like, for example  "40% of the times, you will need to use a turn server"

Comment: This is not only about firewalls, but also some SoHo routers will not use NAT in the way supported by STUN alone. I don't think that some reliable number can be given for such a broad question - it depends too much on who the users of your application are, where they live, how they are connected to the internet ... And it might change over time since infrastructure changes

Comment: Here is some data from [this talk in 2016](https://youtu.be/Y1mx7cx6ckI?t=1025) that is probably outdated but may still be helpful: ranging from around 10% to 25% sessions require relays (TURN server).